# 512 IP in one NIC - ubuntu - is this possible?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

Let's say that I have 1 network card and 2 blocks /24 of IP to assign:

```
150.50.50.0/24
150.60.60.0/24
```

I know, that I can only add 256 virtual interfaces to each NIC from http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/create-virtual-network-adapters-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

How I can add 2 blocks to same NIC?
Should I use VLAN?

Comment: You can probably do this, but it probably is not what you actually need to be doing. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why it is not good?

Comment: @user3746280 why don't you explain the actual problem that you are trying to solve. You're probably falling into the [XY Problem trap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Publicly routable IPv4 addresses are a diminishing resource, make sure you are not frivolously using them up.

Comment: Also, the guide you linked shows the old way of adding addresses, and it should not be used anymore. @andol's answer shows one current way to do it. And you still need to explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to create seo hosting with dedicated IP's for clients. I know, that IPv4 addresses are diminishing resource, but I paid for it a lot. Few companies in my country selling this type of hosting too, and I think, that is good use of IPv4, if clients paying for it.

Comment: Frankly, I think you are wasting a valuable resource. Fundamentally, nobody knows how search engines rank the content they index (its a trade secret). Claiming to know how they do it is insincere at best, especially since there is some semi-authoritative links doing a simple google search to suggest what you are doing has no benefit to SEO.

Comment: http://pressable.com/blog/2013/02/21/do-you-need-a-dedicated-ip-address-for-seo/

Comment: Well, that's not gonna work for SEO, but anyway, has the idea of using a router... or a switch, or other dedicated network device to fulfill your networking needs occurred to you?

Comment: I thought, that question will receive few minus points, if I told this. Maybe you have right, but clients want SEO hosting and pay much more for it, than for normal hosting.

Comment: @user3746280 The downvotes probably have more to do with the fact that the question isn't a good one. It's not useful because putting 512 IPs on a single NIC isn't useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> than setting another VLAN and adding to it virtual interfaces

Sorry dude, this shows you have no idea what you're talking about. Why in the world do you want this anyways?

Are those networks routed to you? Or directly attached? It matters - you'll configure things differently.

Anyway assuming that the networks are routed to you, do something like this, not that eth0:0 nonsense.

```
auto dummy0
iface dummy0 inet static
    pre-up modprobe dummy
    address 150.50.50.0/32
iface dummy0 inet static
    address 150.50.50.1/32
…
iface dummy0 inet static
    address 150.50.50.255/32
```

Answer (score 4):

Assigning 512 additional ip addresses to an interface shouldn't be any problem. Here is me adding 1000 additional addresses, ending up on a total of 1001.

```
root@tbox:~# for c in $(seq 1 4); do for d in $(seq 1 250); do ip addr add 10.0.$c.$d/32 dev eth0; done; done
root@tbox:~# ip addr show eth0 | grep -E "\binet\b" | wc -l
1001
root@tbox:~#
```

Comment: THanks for answer @andol. Is your way is better way (in mean of performance) than setting another VLAN and adding to it virtual interfaces?

Comment: I have no idea what you are really trying to accomplish, and hence no idea what the best solution is. As people keep telling you, you really ought to add a bit more info to your original question.

Comment: I added comment to my question for what I will use ip's.